# Is There Any Idea where is the git menu in the visual studio 2012

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2012

I installed git source control provider on visual studio 2012 (such as: tools -> Extensions and updates then search git and install git source control provider) but i can't see "git" menu.
I installed git extensions with "Visual Studio 11 Integration" and TortoiseGit. I can connect github with these and i can use all git feature from right click context menu. but i want to see git menu on visual studio 2012. Is there any idea where is the git menu?
P.S: I can see git menu in the visual studio 2010.

Comment: What version of git-extensions do you have?

Comment: i've Git Extensions 2.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is outdated, get [the last version](http://gitextensions.googlecode.com/files/GitExtensions243SetupComplete.msi) of Git Extensions (2.43 at this time)